# Karma don’t fail if tests have errors

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner

When a test can’t be run by Karma due to an error (like a syntax error), Karma complains with a warning like that :

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Connected on socket WT-AsaXZq4odkQe2DgZJ with id 10861626
WARN [web-server]: 404: /undefinedhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Ftests%2Funit%2Fjs%2Fspecs%2Fcore%2FDeviceSpec.js%3F1e346ab1ad6e6e9240be6a6d5effaaa8f0dd96d8/9/%22ReferenceError%3A%20Can't%20find%20variable%3A%20SYNTAXERROR%22
```

The last line unescaped is : "/undefinedhttp://localhost:9876/base/tests/unit/js/specs/core/DeviceSpec.js?1e346ab1ad6e6e9240be6a6d5effaaa8f0dd96d8/9/"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SYNTAXERROR""

Which is right since that I inserted SYNTAXERROR somewhere in my test for the purpose of that question.

So the test is ignored but, since other tests are OK, Karma returns that tests have passed :

```
 PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 41 of 41 SUCCESS (0.354 secs / 0.016 secs)
➜ echo $?
0
```

**I want Karma to fail if it can‘t execute all tests** (I don’t think of any reason not to !).

I haven’t found any configuration variable to act that way.

I found the line where Karma print the [warning above](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/482654ce23ef7da6f68955800c6ccea085a2ba7b/lib/middleware/common.js#L22) but I don’t understand why it’s handled as a 404...

Any idea to make Karma fail when it can’t execute all tests ?

Comment: It looks to me that your tests are passing. The problem is that some suites are not loaded, is this right?

Comment: Yes. Due to an error in a suite, the suite isn’t loaded. The problem is that, if you don’t look at warning, you think everything’s ok, which is not.

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap karma and listen to any SyntaxError in your case and force an exit or a failure in such case. Not really sure about the technical detail of it though

Comment: I’ve redirected karma output to a file that I then grep to search for warnings. If so, I fail explicitly. It works but isn’t very elegant...

Comment: Just started using Karma as well, and have the exact same scenario. This seems like a pretty understandable request, not sure why it seems so hard to find an answer.

You mention that you don't know why it's handled as 404, [this might be why](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/482654ce23ef7da6f68955800c6ccea085a2ba7b/lib/middleware/common.js#L56).

Comment: You might be able to write a test to detect this. I found a discussion about doing this with jasmine (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/326) but the concept could probably be applied in most test frameworks.

Comment: How is this not considered a fatal flaw of Karma?

Answer (score 1):

I’m using a script which fails if `WARN` are displayed by karma :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eo pipefail

mkdir -p tests/unit/js/dist || true
./node_modules/.bin/karma start tests/unit/js/karma.conf.js --port 9875 | tee tests/unit/js/dist/results.txt

if grep 'WARN' tests/unit/js/dist/results.txt; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```